# How to prevent foreach from duplicating entries from an HTML table array

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to add multiple entries gathered from a HTML array table to the database but the value of the quantity seems to be duplicating, including the value for remarks. The whole entry seems to be duplicating as well. How can I prevent them from happening?

Here's my PHP code for inserting the table to the database:

```
<?php
    $tmp = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST["inRemarks"])) {
            foreach($_POST["inRemarks"] as $inRemarks) if ($tmp++ < 2) {
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $inQty = $_POST['incQty'];
                foreach ($inQty as $key => $incQty) {
                    $prod = $_POST['prodItem']; 
                    foreach($prod as $prodItem) {
                        $emp = $_POST['emp'];
                        $emp1 = $conn->query("SELECT empID AS empA FROM employee WHERE empName = '$emp'");
                        $emp2 = $emp1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $emp3 = $emp2['empA'];
                        $prod1 = $conn->query("SELECT prodID AS prodA FROM product WHERE prodName = '$prodItem'");
                        $prod2 = $prod1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $prod3 = $prod2['prodA'];
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO incoming (inQty, inDate, receiptNo, inRemarks, empID, prodID)
                        VALUES ('$incQty',CURDATE(),'".$_POST['rcno']."','$inRemarks','$emp3','$prod3')";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql); 
                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's my JavaScript code for the form and table:

```
function validateForm() {
    if(document.getElementById('addRcpt').value == "") {
        alert('Please Enter Receipt Number');
        document.getElementById('addRcpt').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('addQty').value == "") {
        alert('Please Enter Quantity');
        document.getElementById('addQty').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to add this entry?')) {
        alert("Incoming Product Successfully Added");
        return true;        
    }
    else {
        return false;       
    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var current = '';
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }

                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
              regroup(i,rowCount,tableID);
            }
        }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        if(i==1){
            newcell.innerHTML = (rowCount+1)
        }
        else{
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function regroup(i,rc,ti){
    for(j = (i+1);j<rc;j++){
        document.getElementById(ti).rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = j+1;
    }
}
```

Query result:

[image: Query result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested `foreach` loops are multiplying your query and your code is totally not doing what you think it does.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        for ($index = 0; $index < count($_POST['prodItem']; $index++) {

            $inRemarks = $_POST["inRemarks"][$index];
            $prodItem = $_POST['prodItem'][$index];
            $inQty = $_POST['incQty'][$index];
            $emp = $_POST['emp'];

            $emp1 = $conn->query("SELECT empID AS empA FROM employee WHERE empName = '$emp'");
            $emp2 = $emp1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $emp3 = $emp2['empA'];
            $prod1 = $conn->query("SELECT prodID AS prodA FROM product WHERE prodName = '$prodItem'");
            $prod2 = $prod1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $prod3 = $prod2['prodA'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO incoming (inQty, inDate, receiptNo, inRemarks, empID, prodID)
            VALUES ('$incQty',CURDATE(),'".$_POST['rcno']."','$inRemarks','$emp3','$prod3')";
            $result = $conn->query($sql); 

            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ..Thank you very much!! it works!! never knew that for loop is just the solution rather than using multiple foreach..

Comment: You need to understand what you did with your code :) the logic was wrong. It doesn't really matter if you use a for or a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

by filtering your `$_POST["inRemarks"]` and `$_POST['incQty'];` using [array_unique](http://array_unique)

```
if(!empty($_POST["inRemarks"])) {
    $_inRemarks = array_unique($_POST["inRemarks"]); // <<<<<<<<<<
    foreach($_inRemarks as $inRemarks) if ($tmp++ < 2) {
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $inQty = array_unique($_POST['incQty']); // <<<<<<<<<<
// ......
```

Comment: after submit , what's the output of `$_POST['incQty']` and `$_POST["inRemarks"]`

Comment: it only considers the final value and still doubles the quantity and the remarks entered eventhough they are different values. only the final value is considered and it is duplicated in which the first value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You must your **$sql = "INSERT INTO...** move in first foreach loop.

```
foreach($_POST["inRemarks"] as $inRemarks){
.........other foreach loops and rest of code.........
$sql = "INSERT INTO...
}
```

Comment: the final value is still duplicating and the first value is ignored.

Comment: Try to: print_r($_POST);  maybe your arrays have duplicates too.

Comment: ..I have discovered the problem, the foreach seems to be duplicating my values since i have foreach loops.